# template class must be written all in the head file?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have tried to write a template class. It seems that when I write the constructor in classname.cpp
not in classname.h, then it could be compiled correctly.

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Yes, if the compiler does not support the `export` keyword.

Comment: @songyuanyao, That was removed from the C++11 standard.

Comment: anyway what should I do if I want to write them separately

Comment: @chris Sorry I did not know that. So, now we really have to write all defination of a template in head file? (Although rare compilers support `export` so we have to do it in fact)

Comment: @songyuanyao, user: Well, some people like to make .tpp or .tcc or whatever files for template definitions that they include at the bottom of the header. It's not that they have to be implemented in the header, but they can't be in a different translation unit.

Comment: you mean #inlcude ".cpp" in the last of the head file, but if I did this. It says there is a redefinition